# android image rotates when picking from gallery on some device like LG g4

Tags: android, image, bitmap, rotation, exif

my app is supporting image picking from gallery, it works fine with most of the devices.
im having issues with LG g4, and samsung galaxy s6 so far:
every image that was taken from the phones camera will be saved rotated and its exif param remains 0. when i will pick this image from the phones gallery it will return a rotated image (90 degrees) but the exif param is 0.

```
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(data.getPath());
        int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
        int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
        if (rotationInDegrees == 0)
            chosenImage = RotateBitmap(chosenImage, 0);
        else if (rotationInDegrees == 90)
            chosenImage = RotateBitmap(chosenImage, 90);
        else if (rotationInDegrees == 270)
            chosenImage = RotateBitmap(chosenImage, 270);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

exifToDegrees(rotation):

```
private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
        return 90;
    } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
        return 180;
    } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        return 270;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

rotateBitmap(bitmap):

```
public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: Have the same issue now. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I use glide library to handle this problem.

```
Glide.with(this).load("your image uri").asBitmap().toBytes().fitCenter().into(new SimpleTarget<byte[]>() {
      @Override
      public void onResourceReady(byte[] resource, GlideAnimation<? super byte[]> glideAnimation) {
          imageEditorView.resetImage(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(resource, 0, resource.length));
      }
});
```